# TFS Builds, Project Files: Orphaned references to files not being pushed are causing endless build errors

Tags: project

We are using TFS 2010 (Visual Studio) for our deployments and have client code projects (.csproj files) and database projects (.dbproj files) We understand that when our Developers add files to our application there is a corresponding reference to these files in the Project file. If I push a changeset from Dev to QA that includes the project file, and the project file contains a reference to a file that's been added that is not in the changeset, I will receive a build error.

Once we started pushing just changesets (as opposed to performing full builds) this quickly became our number one bottleneck in doing TFS builds. I would deploy the database project and there would be 20 errors. The only way I could correct them was to navigate down the entire solution explorer tree and exclude each orphaned reference individually. This has proved far too time consuming and on the advice of our lead programmer we have returned to doing full builds of QA and UAT.

We are in the early stages of this product, and therefore we will be adding many files for some time. We need a better solution for this problem. Neither the manual exclusions nor asking developers to not check in code until it is ready for qa will suffice for us. Has anybody out there had any experience with this problem and if so how did you deal with it? Thanks!

Jon

Answer (score 1):

Pushing changesets to QA selectively is known as cherry picking and causes the sorts of issues that you are experiencing. This is not the recommended practice, instead setup the Qa build so that successful build is part of checkin. This way that if a part of a fix is missed ( as it may be in multiple change sets ) the build will fail and the checkin cannot be performed.

Second have the developers do the second checkin to QA or merge the dev change sets to Qa and have the team lead coordinate changes to project files by watching for changes by turning on "notify changes made by others " or setting a policy for the dev team. Full builds should always be done as partials do not always pick up the complete pick up the dependency graph.

Comment: The problem with full builds is that it pushes code not ready for QA. The code may be faulty, incomplete, and lead to errors in functionality. These problems won't be necessarily be caught by the build process. Full builds work in Alpha, but we are at the point where we need to selectively push files according to our work items clocking over into QA (and our work items have child-tasks that break out the dependencies). Our biggest issue is adding files to the Project and being forced to push those references over when we just want to push one changeset that contains the project file. Thanks.

Comment: I may have misread your question a little, I assumed that you were moving/merging code to a qa branch which would represent all the code that has been elevated for test and no other. A full build of QA should not be an issue using this model. How are you moving changesets if they are not ready for test in any case?

Comment: I run a daily build in which I push only our TFS Work Items that are in Ready for QA and merge the changesets associated with these Work Items from our Dev branch to our QA Branch. We only move the code for the Requirements and Bugs that are currently Ready For QA. 

Problems occurs when we have a new .csproj or dbproj to push; any files added to the project that are not being pushed in the daily build go in anyway (project files are a dumb-file list and non mergeable) and cause errors. This is a major stumbling block for us and we are hoping others have found a wrkaround

Comment: That was my original point you need to think of the .csproj files and any of the associated changes as atomic either they both go or neither do. You are correct that merging project files cannot be done correctly. In late stage changes changes are reviewed by the team lead and tested in a new ( blank ) workspace to verify that it builds correctly and in some cases tested by QA in DEV.  For that reason every attempt should be made to include both the project file and the associated files in the same changeset. There is no automated solution for this it requires human intervention.

Comment: Thanks Mike. We are developing a large application that is still in it's infancy so there will be many forthcoming adds to the project file. Many of these adds will not be ready for QA when they are added and so will inevitebly cause errors in the QA deployment if the QA deployment contains the project file. Manually excluding files as they fail is not a solution we relish. We were told pushing changesets via work items was our best practice but this problem seems to be a glaring hole - we appreciate your insight

Comment: By definition files that are ready for QA are complete from a development point of view, modified project files cannot be pushed until its dependencies are ready to check in as well, your current process back loads the process because the builds break. Changes to project files need to be coordinated by sr developers otherwise you are buying a world of hurt. Best of luck. If you would lie to talk more offline let me know.